# Performance Issue due to join in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have an issue of taking more time to get data while using left join (3 min). But when trying with inner join, it is taking only less than 20 secs. Since inner join eliminates other records which is no data in respective table, i am not able to get all records. Please help to resolve this.

Query:

```
SELECT UserName, UserEmail, UserLeaveReason FROM [dbo].[UserData] UD WITH (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN #vw_User REQ on UD.UserID= REQ.UserID 
LEFT JOIN Txn_UserLeaveDetails TD ON TD.RELREQID = REQ.RELREQID AND TD.IsActive = 1 
LEFT JOIN MST_LeaveDescription TS ON TS.LeaveDescriptionId = TD.LeaveDescriptionId
```

Txn_UserLeaveDetails : Contains leave details of users, which can be active and inactive(past leaves) . For this query i need only data of current leaves.

```
**Txn_UserLeaveDetails** 
    RELREQID
    UserID
    LeaveStartDate
    LeaveEndDate
    CreatedDate
    CreatedBy
    UpdatedDate
    UpdatedBy
    IsActive
```

MST_LeaveDescription : This table gives the description of Leave Reason.

```
**MST_LeaveDescription**
    LeaveDescriptionId 
    LeaveReason
    CreatedDate
    UpdateDate
```

In the above query output i need all user data irrespective of their leave status. But with the above query it is taking 3 minutes. However when i change join with MST_LeaveDescription to inner join it is taking only 20 secs. But in that case i am getting users with leave.

Please help,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the schema and query plan - otherwise we're just guessing really...

Comment: @NevilleKuyt Sure.. will post now

Comment: For the schema, we really need full DDL - data types, indexes, keys etc. And the query plan (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/explain-transact-sql) is really the only way to figure out what SQL Server is doing

Comment: (1) `UserLeaveReason` is not in any of the tables.  (2) What are the total number of users verses the ones on current leave?  (3) It is confusing to me that the connecting table is a temporary table (`#vw_User`).

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #UserLeave
(
    UserId int index idxUserId,
    UserLeaveReason varchar(200)
)

--get active leaves
insert into #UserActiveLeave(UserId, UserLeaveReason)
select TD.UserID, TS.LeaveReason
from Txn_UserLeaveDetails TD 
join MST_LeaveDescription TS on TD.LeaveDescriptionId = TS.LeaveDescriptionId
where TD.IsActive = 1; 

--get the rest of the users without active leaves
insert into #UserActiveLeave(UserId)
select UserID
from [dbo].[UserData]
except
select UserId
from #UserActiveLeave;

--result
select ud.UserName, ud.UserEmail, ua.UserLeaveReason
from #UserActiveLeave as ua
join [dbo].[UserData] as ud on ua.UserId = ud.UserId;
```